# Local DataTables js blocked by Content Security Policy on Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, datatables, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have download the js for DataTables and I'm trying to load it on my Firefox extension but, its been blocked by Content Security Policy:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“default-src
>   moz-extension://27d54fdf-40f3-4919-9314-f0f8b4715ef6”). Source:
>   onfocusin attribute on DIV element.  options.html
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“default-src
>   moz-extension://27d54fdf-40f3-4919-9314-f0f8b4715ef6”). Source: $(
>   document ).ready(functi....

I've set the Content Security Policy on my manifest.json file:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'"
```

Here is my inclusions on head:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

And my script on the options page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: the first comes from old jquery

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but can't be replicated using a new app.
It only happens on Firefox, not Chrome.
After switching to JQuery 2 or 3 this error is gone.